# Change a specific url to other url in wordpress using function or htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Hi i have a woocommerce product and its url is http://localhost/project/product/my-product/

For this specific url i want to change the url in to

http://localhost/project/my-product/ .

Or some one take http://localhost/project/my-product/ he need to see http://localhost/project/product/my-product/ content without changing .

Is that possible using htaccess or any othe function

Answer (score 0):

you can hook up into redirect rules, here is an article for that https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/change-specific-urls.html